# Как автоматически обновлять страницу на локальном компьютере

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, локальная-сеть

я соединила два компа локально друг к другу, открыла на втором сайт который верстаю, а на первом IDE, чтобы писать код.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы при сохранений кода, на втором компе сайт автоматически обновлялся?

Comment: Вариантов много, все зависит от конечной цели. Есть разные плагины для разных IDE (live server и тому подобные). Можно пользоваться разными сборщиками по типу gulp, webpack.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967825/live-server-vscode-on-another-computer может это?

Comment: https://handhikayp.medium.com/projecting-your-visual-studio-code-live-server-into-another-device-af9163c9ef40 или вот